# What is the proper way to handle multiple clients connections on linux server

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, server

Hi I am writing server on linux in C language using TCP.
The server has to handle multiple connections (up to 5000 approximately). 5000 is max, but average should be about 500 - 1000.
I would like to know what is better to use for handling the clients connections and listening. If is better to use one thread for everyone client or use `select()` function.

1) Thread - every client has his own thread. The thread is listening for client's request and process it.

Select function - one loop with select, where all requests are processing. (something similar to this http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/)

If I would use threads, it would need lot of memory and cpu performance. Therefore, I prefer to use select but I am not sure if select can handle so many connections and if it won't slow down responses from server (there is the loop which has to go through the clients sockets ). So is it OK to use select for so many clients ?

I was looking for my answer but, I haven't found it, or I just don't know what to search. So please don't be upset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, threads are quite costly: each thread wants its call stack (typically megabytes) and consume a task in the scheduler. So the common advice is to have a few dozen threads at most (perhaps using some [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)). Probably a hundred threads could be reasonable (on some powerful server), but many thousands threads probably won't be reasonable: even idle threads are somehow expensive.

So I would recommend using a multiplexing call like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (better than `select` which usually has a hard-coded limit on the number of file descriptors, the builtin size of `fd_set`). You might use in addition a thread pool to serve *active* connections (or requests).

Actually, what you refer to is called the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem). You could also use [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html).

Several [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) libraries are providing some useful infrastructure: [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/), [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) from GTK, ...

BTW, you could have a mixed approach: a pool of processes (perhaps running on different machines) using thread pools.

Notice that some compilers offer [split stacks](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks), and the [goroutines](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines) of the [Go language](http://golang.org/) are designed to enable many "[green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)".

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. It was helpful :) I haven't idea about epoll. I am going to use epoll.

Comment: Did you consider using `libev` ?

Comment: Yes but I do not have such experience. Maybe later. I do not want to complicate it. I've never programmed server so I have to firstly learn something...

Comment: If you do all by yourself, you are likely to make more mistakes and take more time than by using some established library. Is it for fun & learning, or is it for serious work?

Comment: It is a school project :)